# Get the names of all factors with more than one level

Tags: r, r-factor

I have example data as follows:

```
mtcars <- mtcars
# Creates a factor with one level
mtcars$vs <- 1
mtcars$vs <- as.factor(mtcars$vs)
# Creates a factor with 2 levels
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)
```

I would like to simply get the names of all factors with more than one level, so:

```
names_of_factors_with_more_lvls <- "am"
```

What is the shortest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `nlevels` to create a logical condition - use `select` to select the columns where it is `factor` class, and short circuit (`&&`) it with the next condition, and retreive the column names

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
   select(where(~ is.factor(.x) && nlevels(.x) > 1)) %>%
   names
[1] "am"
```

---

Slightly more compact would be

```
library(collapse)
names(gv(fact_vars(mtcars), \(x) fnlevels(x) > 1))
[1] "am"
```

or otherwise specify the `return`

```
gv(fact_vars(mtcars), \(x) fnlevels(x) > 1, return = 'names')
[1] "am"
```

Comment: Interesting to see collapse included. Have you found the package easy to learn compared to others suchas as dplyr/data.table?

Answer (score 4):

Another base R sol'n:

```
sapply(mtcars, \(x) nlevels(x) > 1) |> which() |> names()
# [1] "am"
```

Or

```
Filter(\(x) nlevels(x) > 1, mtcars) |> names()
```

Comment: Actually, this is not the logic I used if you check my code correctly (so I removed the reference to my post)

Comment: Cool. I was studying your collapse solution when I got the idea of using Filter().

Comment: Thanks.  My solution was applying the code only on the factor columns (after subsetting with `fact_vars`.  That is the reason I meant your logic was slightly different from mine

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```r
names(mtcars[, sapply(mtcars, function(x) length(levels(x))) > 1, drop = F])
#[1] "am"
```